# apache server: redirect all url request to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using apache server on my mac, everything works well.

Now I have a webpage, whose `index.php` is quite complex: 
In `index.php`, it expects url like: `localhost/~username/hostname/page_a`.
And the content of `page_a` is actually a `.php` file stored in `content` folder.
So in `index.php`, it just parses `page_a`, and do a include: '' to render the request page.

But In `.htaccess`, the redirect rule was not properly configured.

For example, if I click a link: `localhost/~username/hostname/page_a`,
is there any way to redirect this url to `index.php`,
and at the same time, the url will still be `localhost/~username/hostname/page_a`,
so that `index.php` can parse and render it correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how this `index.php` handles the request. If it simply looks in the `$_SERVER` variables like `'REQUEST_URI'` to find the requested file, then you don't need to pass it anything. If it looks for a query string parameter, the your rewrite rule needs to pass it that.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Or if you need to pass it query string param:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Without the `R` flag or an `http://` in the rule, the URL address bar on the browser won't change. If someone types in `http://localhost/~username/hostname/page_a` in their browser, the `/~username/hostname/page_a` request gets sent to the server, the rewrite rule would internally rewrite it to `/index.php`, and the php script can look either in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to find the `/~username/hostname/page_a` request and properly route it, or in the `$_GET['url']` parameter if the second rule is used.